SVG in JS, script elements do not work in iPhone
I have written interactive HTML page using SVG in JS. This is my first time coding in JS and using SVG as well so please forgive me if I'm missing something basic. Below is source that shows this issue. It works correctly without issues in Chrome and Safari on my Macbook, works on Amazon tablet browser, works on Chorome in my Windows browser. DOES NOT work on my iPhone 13 Chrome or Safari. So this listing below is code from https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_scripting.asp that shows the same issue where the dynamic changes in the script does not work. Any solutions is greatly appreciated.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>SVG script Element</h2>

<svg width="200" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="circle1" cx="50" cy="50" r="25" style="fill:red;" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

<input type="button" value="Change Radius"  onclick="changeRadius()" />

<script>
function changeRadius() {
  document.getElementById("circle1").setAttribute("r", "50");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>


I can load HTML file into browsers on Mac, Windows, Amazon Tablet, the circle radius changes when you click on the button. This does not happen on Chrome or Safari on my iPhone 13 running iOS 17.6.1.

Instead of changing the attribute, change the property's baseVal value.
NOTE
I changed your code in the following ways and for the following reasons:

<input> to <button>, since the latter one is recommended
Added a id to the <button> for easier selection via JS
Inline onclick to JS .addEventListener, because the latter one is recommended



function changeRadius() {   
  const circle = document.getElementById('circle1');
  circle.r.baseVal.value = 50;
}

document
  .getElementById('changeRadius')
  .addEventListener('click', changeRadius);
<svg width="200" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="circle1" cx="50" cy="50" r="25" style="fill:red;" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>

<button type="button" id="changeRadius">Change radius</button>




Thanks for the details. So I have noticed something. The same source works on my iPhone when I browse over to the example at https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_scripting.asp. So, the browser on iPhone must be loading HTML files differently from a local file compared to accessing from http. How does one load a HTML file into the browser on iPhone?

Your questions states that "[...] that shows the same issue where the dynamic changes in the script does not work.", your comment now says "The same source works on my iPhone when I browse over to the example [...]". Maybe you should decide if it works or if it does not work.
